# Negative expressions in passé composé

Tags: grammaire, négation, ordre-des-mots, passé-composé

How are negative expressions (*ne pas*, *ne aucun(e)*, *ne que*, *ne jamais*, *ne plus*)  formed in the passé composé and is there a way to predict whether it forms around or after the auxilary?

Answer (score 13):

There is no such thing as "or after" the auxiliary. The negative of these forms is formed by wrapping the ne+pas/whatever circumfix around the auxiliary **and any accompanying pronoun**:

> *Je ne **m'en suis** pas moqué.*
>
> *Je ne **l'ai** pas frappé.*
>
> etc.

In most spoken forms of French (and writing that emulates them), the *ne* is almost universally dropped, which is the only way I can think of that one could describe a negative as being placed "after" the auxiliary.

Answer (score 4):

in passé composé most of the adverbs come in between the auxiliary verb and the past participle.

**example:**

- Je **ne** suis **jamais** allé en France.
- Je **n'** ai **rien** compris.
- Je **n'** ai **pas encore** mangé.

**BUT:**

- Je **n'** ai vu **personne**.
- **Personne n'** est venu.
- **Rien n'** a changé.

**NOTE:** Adverbs of place and time come after the past participle

**example:**

- Nous avons parlé **hier**.
- Je ne suis allé **nulle part**.

***SOURCE: apprenons le français- méthode de français (4)***

Answer (score 0):

The above picture gives a basic explanation of negative expressions au passe(https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvYXb.jpg)

Comment: Ceci manque un peu d'explications.